# Prove that a differentiable function f with $f'(x) \geq f(x)^2$ is non positive and has limit $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, with $f'(x) \geq f(x)^2$, be a differentiable function. I must prove that $f(x)\leq 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$

As $f'(x) \geq f(x)^2 \geq 0$, $f$ is non decreasing. So, if I have $\lim_{x \to \infty} = 0$, it is easy to prove that $f(x) \leq 0$.

But I'm stuck on proving $\lim_{x \to \infty} = 0$

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: I think you mean you want to prove $f(x) \leq 0$, not $f'(x) \leq 0$.

Comment: Yes, it is $f(x) \leq 0$, I got it wrong, thanks

Comment: mostly,i f it is ever positive, $f$ blows up in finite time. examples $y' = 1 + y^2,$ get $y = \tan x.$ For $y' = y^2,$ with $y(0) = 1$ we get $y = 1/(1-x)$

Comment: It is not given that f '  is continuous so integrating f'' may not be allowed .However solving the problem with f' continuous is hare enough.

Comment: When NullUser says Integrating from y to x he is not using integration theory but only that if a derivative is non negative then the function is nondecreasing . So f differentiable  is sufficient .Nice job Nulluser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f' \geq 0$, $f$ is an increasing function and hence $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ exists, but may possibly be infinite. If $L>0$, then there is some $y$ with $f(y)>0$. Then $f'(x)/f^2(x) \geq 1$ for all $x>y$. Then since $1/f$ is also differentiable on the interval $[y,\infty]$, for each $x>y$  the mean value theorem implies we have 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{f(y)}-\frac{1}{f(x)}}{x-y} = \frac{f'(c_x)}{f(c_x)^2} \geq 1$$
for some $c_x$ depending on $x$ between $x$ and $y$.
In particular we find
$$
\frac{1}{f(y)}-\frac{1}{f(x)} \geq x-y.
$$
The right side tends to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$, but the left side is at most $\frac{1}{f(y)}$, a contradiction.
Thus it must be that $L \leq 0$. In particular, $L$ is finite (it clearly can't be $-\infty$). Now take the liminf as $x \to \infty$ on both sides of
$f'(x) \geq f(x)^2$ to find
$$
\liminf_{x \to \infty} f'(x) \geq L^2.
$$
If $L \neq 0$, then this would say that $f'(x) > L^2-\epsilon$ for all $x$ large enough, which would in particular show that $f$ eventually becomes strictly positive, again leading to a contradiction. Thus it must be that $L=0$.

Comment: could you explain how you got to $1\leq\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}$?

Comment: Since $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x\geq y$, we can divide the inequality $f'(x) \geq f(x)^2$ without changing the inequality.

Comment: You can't necessarily integrate $f'/f^2.$ Use the MVT instead.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for pointing out this serious error I made. I have fixed it using MVT as you suggested.